# Why is the load in nodetool status output much less than utilised disk space?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have 3 node cluster and upon checking the nodetool status; Load is just less than 100 GB on all three nodes. The replication factor is two and percentage own is 65-70% for all three.

However when I inspected the /data directory it is having index.db files for size more than 400 GB and the total size of the keyspace directory is more than 700GB.

Any idea on why a huge gap??

Let me know if any extra details are required :)

PS: nodetool listsnapshots command shows an empty list (No snapshots)

Analysis - we tried redeploying the setup but still the same results; tried researching this topic but no luck.

Expectation - I was expecting this difference in the load and the size of data directory to be negligible if not zero.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. Also, this is a duplicate of the same question you asked on [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321984/) which I've already responded to. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, your response on the stack exchange was not the case; I think I responded to that answer by explaining. Also, I am relatively new to the platform so wasn't familiar that on the stack overflow what kind of questions are preferred on this site.
Thanks for letting me know about the categories preferred; will keep them in mind.

As for the question, I still don't have an answer on either sites.